# vertical equation for a Multiplication of two numbers expression

Tags: equations, format

I'm using Latex to write a manual multiplication calculation, like in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Multiplication_of_two_numbers

I do this in the equation editor of zim-wiki, that uses Latex. This should express the calculation 218 * 2 = 463, formated in a vertical way, like:

[image]

so i think the formula should be: (tested in https://www.overleaf.com and seems ok)

Also checked the documentation here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Multiplication_of_two_numbers

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{
    \begin{array}[b]{r}
      \left 218 \right\\
      \times \left 2 \right
    \end{array}
  }{
    \left( 436 \right)
  }
\end{equation}
```

But in zim i get 2 errors:

1. the expression image wont be generated
2. the error log shows "! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter."

I thought this would be because of of some missing dependency, but i checked on the MiKTex console, and all the dependencies () in https://zim-wiki.org/manual/Plugins/Equation_Editor.html and they seem ok:

[image]

Also, i tried simpler expressions, like

```
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 = 3 
\end{equation}
```

and the result is the same. I'm using windows 10. Any ideas?

(Update)

extrapolating Fran example, to show a calculation with a double digit multiplicator

[image]

```
\begin{array}{ccccc}
  & & 2 &      1 & 8 \\
  & & \times & 3 & 2 \\\hline
 \\[-1em]
  & & 4 &      3 & 6 \\
+ & 6 & 5 &    4 &    \\\hline
  & 6 & 9 &    7 & 6 
\end{array}
```

Comment: \frac{\begin{array}{r} 218 \\ \times 2 \end{array} }{436}           works for me and is more simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\opmul{218}{2}
\end{document}
```

Without packages, this works in the LaTeX equation plugin of Zim:

```
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 8\\
 & \times & 2\\\hline
 \\[-10pt]
4 & 3 & 6
\end{array}
```

[image: mwe]

Or maybe this more compacted convoluted versión:

```
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
& 2 & 1 & 8\\[-10pt]
\times &  &  & \\[-10pt]
 & & & 2 \\\hline
 \\[-12pt]
& 4 & 3 & 6
\end{array}
```

[image: mwe3]

Comment: that third solution was the best one for me. And now i can extrapolate, and have a multiplicator with many digits